# I want to change the font of my minitoc

Tags: fonts, minitoc

I am changing the font in my preamble using

```
\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but my minitoc is still in the default font

I am implemeting the minitoc with:

```
\usepackage{minitoc}
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{}
\mtcsetfont{minitoc}{*}{}

%minitoc depth
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3} 
\addtocontents{minitoc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
```

but I don't know what to do with the `\mtcsetfont` command

any ideas?

Comment: Hi Samir, Welcome to TeX.SE Have you taken the [tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone new to LaTeX stumbles across this question, this worked for me...

```
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\renewcommand{\mtifont}{\large\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSSfont}{\small\sffamily}
```